# node.js https.get() res confusion between header and body

Tags: node.js, https

I recently start learning node.js,

In node.js https module I make a server request with `https.get();` and i `console.dir(res.header)`  this give me the response header, but when I try to `console.dir(res.body)` this give me `undefined`;

I did some investigation on the internet, and I have seen that I need to call data event to log the body. It's make me confused, why can't I log body directly, and the data format for header is string and for body is buffer?

Comment: Are you trying to log the response from your get request? In that case you need to add a console.log in your successresponse method.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some examples of using the https.request method (same as get), they should show you some ways to use the method. These examples use the httpbin.org site, a very useful one for playing around with this kind of code.

```
const https = require ('https');

// Example 1
// This will return the IP address of the client
var request = https.request({ hostname: "httpbin.org", path: "/ip" },  (res) => {
    console.log('/ip', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log('/ip response: ', d.toString());
    });
});

request.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

request.end();

// Example 2
// This will return some simple data about the get request
request = https.request({ hostname: "httpbin.org", path: "/get"},  (res) => {
    console.log('/get', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log('/get response: ', d.toString());
    });
});
request.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

request.end();

// Example 3
var data = JSON.stringify({firstName: 'Mike', secondName: 'Jones'});
// This will return the data passed request
request = https.request({ hostname: "httpbin.org", path: "/anything", method: "GET", headers: 
    { 'Content-Length': data.length, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }},  (res) => {
    console.log('/anything', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log('/anything response: ', d.toString());
    });
});

request.write(data);
request.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

request.end();
```